# Why auto reload embed flash in Firefox

Tags: html, embed

I load flash by embed element, like this:

```
<div id="game_container">
  <embed src="http://www.flash1890.com/swf2/mtv/20130516/ltt.swf" width="600px" height="600px"></embed>
</div>
```

When this flash loaded success, I execute some code:

```
1. jQuery("#game_container").css("display", "none")
2. jQuery("#game_container").css("display", "block")
```

The flash reload in Firefox, but other browsers don't reload.

So, how to fix this issue? i don't want reload flash in FF.

Comment: because I load amaya game by embed, so must use embed element to test it.